# SQL help- What is wrong with this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SSMS- What did I do wrong in this query? the error message says

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.

but i'm just not seeing it. Please help!

```
INSERT INTO newtable (code, [Description], PACV21, CMSV22, CMSV23, RxV05, PACE_PYMNT, CMS_PYMNT, CMSV22_PYMNT, CMSV23_PYMNT, Rx_PYMNT, 2019 as DatasetYear)
SELECT code, [Description], PACV21, CMSV22, null, RxV05, PACE2018PYMNT, CMS2018PYMNT, null, null, Rx2018PYMNT, 2018 as DatasetYear,
     CASE WHEN PAC2018PYMNT = 'Yes' THEN 1 
          WHEN CMS2018PYMNT = 'Yes' THEN 1 
          WHEN Rx2018PYMNT = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
SELECT code, [Description], PACV21, CMSV22, CMSV23, RxV05, PAC2019PYMNT, null, CMSV22_2019PYMNT, CMSV23_2019PYMNT, Rx2019PYMNT, 2019 as DatasetYear,
    CASE WHEN PAC2019PYMNT = 'Yes' THEN 1
         WHEN CMSV22_2019PYMNT = 'Yes' THEN 1
         WHEN CMSV23_2019PYMNT = 'Yes' THEN 1
         WHEN Rx2019PYMNT = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM tableB
```

Comment: Count the insert columns. How many? Count the select list columns. How many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert statement has 12 values and your select statements have 13. What column are you trying to put the case statement into? It looks like you are missing a column for it.

Comment: @DanialWayne Oh, I did not realize a case statement counts as a value. Do I just add the case statement into the INSERT statement?

Comment: You would need a column in the 'newtable' to place the value into, the CASE statement can stay where it currently is.

Comment: @DanialWayne Thank you!

Comment: Glad you found your answer. Please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points.